# Combining columns of two csvs into one csv via Powershell

Tags: arrays, shell, powershell, csv, integer

Could do with somebodies guidance on this one, got a little bug that's driving me nuts and it would be great if somebody could point out what my problem is.

I have two .csv (comma delimited) files, the first structured like this (but with more records):

```
Name                               Count
C:\users\user1\documents, .docx     12
C:\users\user1\documents, .xlsx     5
```

and the second csv structured like so:

```
FileSize
 3456
 5682
```

I am trying to select the two columns in the first csv and the first column in the second csv and create a new property to form results like this:

```
   Name                               Count    FileSize
   C:\users\user1\documents, .docx     12        3456
   C:\users\user1\documents, .xlsx     5         5682
```

My code so far is:

```
$csvarray = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Test02.csv"
$csvarray2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Test03.csv"
$csvarray += $csvarray2

$csvarray | Select-Object -Property {$_.Name}, {[int]$_.Count}, {[int]$_.FileSize}
```

And the results I am getting are quite frustrating:

```
   Name                               Count    FileSize
   C:\users\user1\documents, .docx     12         0
   C:\users\user1\documents, .xlsx     5          0
                                       0         3456
                                       0         5682
```

I presume that although I have created an array to merge these two csv files, it is still attempting to select results from a column that does not exist in my primary csv which essentially returns NULL or "0" in this case.

Could anybody help I would much appreciate this.

*EDIT
I would just like to add that matching up the file size to file extension does not matter because this will always be accurate thanks to my primary shell scripts which split the original data into two separate csvs so this is not a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add to array, you need to **extend** the original object with new properties:

```
$c1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Test02.csv"
$c2 = ...
$c1 | % {$i=0} { $c1[$i] | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FileSize -NotePropertyValue $c2[$i++].FileSize;}
$c1 | Export-Csv combined.csv
```

Comment: Booyah, everyday is a schoolday. I now know how to use the extend function to apply new properties. Thank you ever so much! & for your rapid response, what a guy :-).